# Getting the derivative of this time dependent vector.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vectors

This vector is time dependent with the following formula:

$$
\begin{align} 
\vec b(\color{blue}{t}) = & \ ( \color{#e69900}{r} \cos(\color{#e69900}{\omega} \color{blue}{t})+\color{#e69900}{l}\sin \color{blue}{\theta} \cos \color{blue}{\phi})\color{#e69900}{\hat i} \\
& +(\color{#e69900}{r}\sin(\color{#e69900}{\omega} \color{blue}{t})+\color{#e69900}{l}\sin \color{blue}{\theta} \sin \color{blue}{\phi})\color{#e69900}{\hat j} \\
& -\color{#e69900}{l}\cos \color{blue}{\theta}\  \color{#e69900}{\hat k}
\end{align}$$

$\begin{align}
\text{I have colored } & \text{time dependents } \color{blue}{\text{blue}} \text{.} \\
& \text{and constants } \color{#e69900}{\text{golden}} \text{.} \\
\end{align}$

How can I calculate $\vec{\dot b}(\color{blue}{t})$ and $\vec{\ddot b}(\color{blue}{t})$ ?

I know basic derivative rules, but this one is hard for me. please help.

My main problem is with taking the derivative of $\sin \color{blue}{\theta} \cos \color{blue}{\phi}$.  Should I apply the chain rule or the product rule first?

Comment: derivative of a vector is the sum of derivatives of its components along the given axes.... and to go on you can even use product rule

Comment: @Jasser. that may seem easy to you. but not for me. and I can't have any mistakes in this thing.

Comment: Have you tried? where were you stuck at?

Comment: @Jesser. when taking the derivative of $\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)$, it's a product and should obey product rule. also it has chain functions, so it should obey it ,too. which rule to use first now ?confused.

Comment: First apply the product rule and you will see chain rule emerging out...

Comment: Derivative of $sin(\theta)cos(\phi)$ with respect to t = (Derivative of $sin(\theta)$ with respect to t)*$cos(\phi)$+(Derivative of $cos(\phi$) with respect to t)*$sin(\theta)$

Comment: After doing this you can use the chain rule to find the derivatives of sin and cos functions

Comment: @Jasser so it will be this? $$\cos\theta \ \dot{\theta} \cos\phi -\sin\phi \ \dot{\phi}\sin\theta$$

Comment: yes! and proceed similarly for the next derivative

Comment: @Jasser so turn that into an answer. that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comment derivative of a vector is the sum of derivatives of its components along the given axes so take the derivatives

Then use product rule and you will see the chain rule emerging out.

Proceed in a similar way to find out the second derivative...